# Bootstrap 3 daterange select in form

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add daterange (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) select to my bootstrap 3 form.
I've added form element to my form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Dates range</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker">
            <input type="text" class="input-small" name="start"/>
            <span class="add-on">to</span>
            <input type="text" class="input-small" name="end"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I get weird looking inputs:

[image]

I would like it to look as [here](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=range&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox).

How should I build my form to get this daterange to look nice? I would like to have those 2 inputs and "to" to be same width as other inputs and have same focus color.

Here is my form to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/a3NV4/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See here example.

To work on Bootstrap 3
http://jsfiddle.net/a3NV4/4/

```
<div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="input-small form-control" name="start" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
        <input type="text" class="input-small form-control" name="end" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({});
```

Comment: Thanks, works as expected :) BTW extra div inside isn't needed, You can add `input-group` class to datepicker div

Answer (score 1):

You are working with Bootstrap 3 and the datepicker plugin is for bootstrap 2.3, that is the problem. So you have to use the according bootstrap 3 classes:

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u7FEP/)

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="input-small form-control" name="start" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-small form-control" name="end" />
</div>
```